# Multiple views using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon

Tags: wpf, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

I have a WPF ribbon application using `Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon`. I can set the view through the `Grid.Row` tag:

```
    </ribbon:Ribbon>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
      <!-- View's content here -->
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</ribbon:RibbonWindow>
```

**Q:** How can I change the view depending on the selected ribbon tab?

Comment: The selected ribbon tab shouldn't change the view. Are you looking for a restyled tab control instead?

Comment: Maybe it shouldn't, but what if you really wanted it to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. Hook the [`SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) event and trade out your view's content. If you're using Prism, you could probably create a [`SelectorRegionAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.composite.presentation.regions.selectorregionadapter.aspx) to do this for you.
2. You could bind to `Ribbon.SelectedValue` (setting `SelectedValuePath` to say `Label`) and provide a `DataTrigger` which handles each of your tab's names.
3. You could put an instance of each view model (assuming your `RibbonWindow`s data context has each of the view models you need) you care about in the `RibbonTab.Tag` property, and adapt your view based on `SelectedItem.Tag`:

   ```
   <r:Ribbon x:Name="PART_Ribbon" ...>
       <r:RibbonTab Tag="{Binding HomeViewModel}" ... />
   </r:Ribbon>
   <Grid>
       <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Tag,
                                         ElementName=PART_Ribbon}" />
   </Grid>
   ```

Comment: I don't know if your suggested solutions will work, but I believe your answer is good enough. Will test this when I return to this project! Thanks.